# jQuery não encontra elementos adicionados via append

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho a seguinte requisição que lista os alunos em uma tabela:

```
jQuery('#presencaExibir').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
       }
   });
   jQuery.ajax({
     url: "/presenca/alunos",
     method: 'post',
     data: {
        sala: jQuery('#sala').val(),
        horario: jQuery('#dia-horario').val()
     },
     success: function(result){
        $('#diaChamada').text($('#dia-semana option:selected').text());

        $('#listaAlunos').text('');

        $.each(result.alunos, function(k, aluno){
            $('#listaAlunos').append(
                "<tr>" +
                    "<div class='row'>" +
                        "<td class='id-aluno'>" + aluno.ID_Aluno + "</td>" +
                        "<td class='col-6'>" + aluno.Nome + "</td>" +
                        "<td><i class='material-icons presenca presente'> account_circle </i></td>" +
                    "</div>" +
                "</tr>"
            );
        });
     }});
});
```

O que eu preciso fazer é pegar todos os valores no td de classe "id-aluno" via jQuery e enviar em outra requisição ajax:

```
jQuery('#finalizarBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
       }
   });
   jQuery.ajax({
     url: "/presenca/finalizar-dia",
     method: 'post',
     data: {
        alunos: $('.id-aluno').text()
     },
     success: function(result){
        console.log(result.alunos);
     }});
});
```

Porém, quando eu tento fazer isso, o resultado que eu tenho de `$('.id-aluno').text()` é

> undefined

Como posso pegar esses valores inseridos na tabela dinamicamente?

Comment: Se você tem vários elementos com a classe `id-aluno` a sua busca `$('.id-aluno')` irá retornar uma lista de elementos, que não possui o método `text`.

Comment: @Anderson, todas as consultas do jQuery retornam uma lista, mesmo que você procure um único elemento. O método `.text()` retorna o `innerText` do primeiro elemento dessa lista. @Antony, poderia adicionar seu HTML e o retorno do Ajax na sua pergunta, de modo que ela se torne testável?

Comment: @user140828 Não é bem assim. O `$('.id-aluno').text()` irá retornar o texto de todos os elementos com a classe `.id-aluno`, não apenas do primeiro.

Comment: Antony, acho que vc está equivocado confundindo as coisas. O `$('.id-aluno').text()` nunca irá retonar `undefined`, mesmo que não haja nenhum elemento com essa classe.

Comment: @Sam obrigado por me atentar. Na verdade eu estava confundindo as coisas mesmo e o undefined estava vindo de um tratamento errado que eu estava fazendo dentro do PHP. Consegui resolver aqui.